# How does psycopg2's connection_factory work?

Tags: python, psycopg2

Can someone explain what psycopg2's connection_factory is and how to use it?

I've been looking at a project's code that connects to postgres via the connection_factory and I am at a lost. I have looked at the docs, https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html, but all it tells me is:

```
Using the connection_factory parameter a different class or connections factory can be specified. It should be a callable object taking a dsn string argument.
```

Looking at the `cursor factories` and `connection` becomes overwhelming and I don't even know if it is still related to the `connection_factory`.

Below is the code that I am looking at:

```
class PsycoConnection(psycopg2.extensions.connection):
    def lobject(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Somewhere in another class the above class gets called as follows:

```
result = psycopg2.connect(
                connection_factory=PsycoConnection,
                **connection_info)
```

Normally when I use psycopg2 to connect to a database I simple do something like below:

```
result = psycopg2.connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5433 dbname=yugabyte sslmode=prefer")
```

I know the `connection_info` is not any different to `"host=127.0.0.1 port=5433 dbname=yugabyte sslmode=prefer"` except it's a dict. So my question is what is this `PsycoConnection` passed to `connection_factory`? To me the `PsycoConnection` class isn't even doing anything since the only code is `pass`. Thank you.

Comment: Where are seeing `PsycoConnection`? What you show is not going to change anything from the regular connection as the only method it defines does nothing.

Comment: The github project is here: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/sql_db.py, line 570 is the class ```PsycoConnection```, line 656 is where it's being used

Comment: Alright so it looks like they are overriding this [lobject](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html?highlight=lobject#connection.lobject) to make it a no-op. In other words not allow for working with large objects. You would have to ask the `odoo` project folks to confirm and the why of it.